# Where is Thunderbird in Ubuntu software center? 18.04 Minimal install

Tags: software-installation, software-center, thunderbird, 18.04

I think its supposed to be there, but I cant find it, and it won't show when I search for it.
I have not changed anything in the "Software & Updates window".

I used the minimal install option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called Thunderbird Mail and you can search for *thunderbird* in Ubuntu Software or install it from the terminal with the command:

```
sudo apt install thunderbird
```

Lighting is the Mozilla Calendar extension for Thunderbird, based on Sunbird - the Mozilla Standalone Calendar application. It is tightly  integrated with Thunderbird, allowing it to easily perform email-related calendaring tasks. To install lightning type:

```
sudo apt install xul-ext-lightning
```

[image]

Comment: Copy/pasted thunderbird but the search still only shows :
Mailspring 
Hiri
KMail Import Wizard.

But the terminal command worked so i got it installed, thanks :)

Comment: thunderbird:
  Installed: 1:52.7.0+build1-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1:52.7.0+build1-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 1:52.7.0+build1-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

but now i have installed via terminal. it still wont show in software center

Comment: @e2tab10 Consider reporting a bug (probably against the software center) to the ubuntu project.